# Does OAuth2.0 authenticate every request?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have a project that leverages googles OAuth servers for authentication but I’m confused how the user stays authenticated throughout the session. It doesn’t seem like my resource server interacts with googles auth server for every request just the initial login authorization. I noticed that there is an access token of some sort sent to my resource server upon a successful authentication with an expiration but it’s not saved anywhere or at least I’m not saving it manually, just the principal. So basically, is every request being authenticated or is oauth just for the initial login?

Comment: I think your leveraging googles identity server for authentication.    The access token returned is good for an hour and gives you access to the users profile data.   Its probably being refreshed automatically for you.

Comment: Okay good to know so if I wanted to implement a local login in addition to using login with google I would have to create my own authentication server and manage access tokens manually?

Comment: @KaiLarson It depends on the type of authentication. You could always add form login or basic auth to to your resource server to access it.